# How to make overlapping vectors from entries of a vector?

Tags: r

Just to simplify my question, assume I have a vector x<-c(1:12)and would like to make a list form x like below:

```
x : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

    list[[1]]: 1,2,3,4,5,6 
    list[[2]]: 3,4,5,6,7,8 
    list[[3]]: 5,6,7,8,9,10 
    list[[4]]: 7,8,9,10,11,12 
    list[[5]]: 9,10,11,12,1,2 
    list[[6]]: 11,12,1,2,3,4
```

As you can see, neighbor vectors have 4 overlapping values and the last vector is wrapped around with the first vector.

What would be a fast and clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
x2 <- c(x,x)
lapply(seq(1, length(x)-1, 2), function(i)x2[i:(i+5)])
```

Comment: Not exactly. The list should contain 6 vectors `list(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)` but this code gives me 11.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! Your edited answer works perfectly and it is indeed very short and clean. Thank you very much.